# Android imageview supported image types like png , jpeg and etc

Tags: android, bitmap, android-imageview

What are the  image formats supported by [android imageview](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html) ? I am getting images from web services and my application supports android 4.0 and above. 
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Supported media formats are : PNG, BMP, WEBP, JPEG and GIF(for Android 4 and above)

Supported media formats: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

Comment: but in my case png images only displaying , am getting image from web service

Comment: @Ydder try to get images from web-services and saved into your storage and then load as a Bitmap